# How to edit the contents of an existing PDF programmatically in JAVA

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

Let's assume I have an existing pdf with a fixed header and footer and blank body like the below image

[image: Empty PDF template]

And I have to add content to the body(white part in the image)

How can I do that in java?

Comment: Re PDFBox, please have a look at the examples in the source code download. Start with HelloWorld.java.

Comment: I have created a pdf from scratch in iText but not sure about pdfBox

will it possible with pdfBox

Comment: In either case you can create the body text on fresh empty pages as usual done with the respective library and then underlay your template page under each of the pages with body content.

Comment: How can we underlay template page under a page with body in java

Comment: In PDFBox you create a PDPageContentStream with the append option in the parameters. Make sure that the fifth parameter is true.

Comment: Depending on the iText version, there are different ways to do that (for example underlaying in page events while you create the body content regularly or underlaying in a second pass after the body content is created, or...). Unfortunately you in your question give hardly any information on the context, don't show what you've tried and where that failed, ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("./the-pdf-where-you-want-to-insert-into.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("./destination.pdf"));

    PdfReader r = new PdfReader("./the-pdf-you-want-to-insert.pdf");
    PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(r, 1);

    Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);

    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y); // x y positions where you want insert
    at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(instance.getScaledWidth(), instance.getScaledHeight()));

    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    canvas.addImage(instance, at);

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

With PdfReader and PdfWriter from iText, you can load a PDF file, do some modification then write it to another location.

Sample code:

```
    String srcPdf = "source-path.pdf";
    String destPdf = "destination-path.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcPdf);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(destPdf);

    try (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer)) {

        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(1);

        // change pdf file starts here
        String imgPath = "image-path.jpg";
        ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(imgPath);

        // create page canvas
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

        // create AT
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(page.getPageSize().getWidth() / 10, page.getPageSize().getHeight() / 10);
        at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(page.getPageSize().getWidth() * 8 / 10, page.getPageSize().getHeight() * 8 / 10));

        float[] matrix = new float[6];
        at.getMatrix(matrix);

        // add image data
        pdfCanvas.addImageWithTransformationMatrix(imageData, matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3], matrix[4], matrix[5]);

        pdfCanvas.release();
    }
```